# Set content of row xml element / add attributes to sub-elements in Kettle XML output?

Tags: xml, output, pentaho, kettle

My *Parent XML element* is called `Rows` (XML root node), and *Row XML element* is called `Row`.

I can output fields as attributes of `Row`, or have sub-elements with their content set to the source field value.

```
<Rows>
  <Row attr1="..." attr2="...">
    <Elem1>...</Elem1>
    <Elem2>...</Elem2>
  </Row>
</Rows>
```

Is there a way however, to set the content of `Row`? Or add attributes to a sub-element? `..` or a blank element name do not work.

```
<Rows>
  <Row attr1="..." attr2="...">
    ...
  </Row>
</Rows>
```

Or

```
<Rows>
  <Row>
    <Elem1 attr1="..." attr2="..."></Elem1>
  </Row>
</Rows>
```

Comment: Need example of structure, what u need exactly. If u are interested only in possibility, then from what u said i state "It is possible". You have to use "XML Join" and "Add XML" steps. I managed to create very complicated structures and multilevel xml document. There is an example in kettle distribution called "creating multilevel XML files" - it is in $KETTLE_HOME/sample directory

Answer (score 1):

As @simar commented, your question is kinda vague, but I think I can give you some light. As he mentioned, It's possible - here's an example of a multilevel and complicated XML being created:
[image: huge transformation that creates XML]
I'm gonna focus on that first sub-transformation "header", since it already has multiple elements and attributes:
[image: smaller transformation that creates the XML "header"]
I'm gonna squeeze some here, unless I'll fill this up with too much images. First, the data grid with some attributes, the "Add XML" step config, and a preview (sorry about the blur):
[image: detailed input, Add XML and preview]
As you can see with the colored boxes, fields are fed to the Add XML step, and there you configure if they are attributes or elements.

- Blue fields were added on that first Data Grid from picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Tlx.png), and
  were used on the Add XML step as attributes of element
  "documentoDLO".
- Red fields were added on that "placeholder" Add
  Constants step, mapped as "not attributes" (hence, elements) on the
  Add XML step, and show up as elements nested on "documentoDLO"...

Just don't ask me why those elements don't close on themselves (being  instead of  ), I sadly don't know how to explain that. But don't worry about that, as soon as we XML Join, it gets fixed. So, on to the next step: JOIN! I'm gonna need two screens on this one:
[image: detailed "Add XML 2" step]
Ok, see on the preview panel how "Add XML 2" turned two fields into 2 attributes. Now, on to "XML Join":
[image: detailed XML Join]
Here you can see how "Add XML" is the target step - or, the one where information will be joined INTO. And source step is Add XML 2, where the information we want to join on the XML stream currently is. The path statement defines where the XML source field will be inserted on the target XML - since we defined "//limitesInformados", those two rows from "Add XML 2" became two sub-elements of

An example of the file created by this process can be found [here](http://www.bcb.gov.br/fis/pstaw10/DLO2061_exemplo_v201501.xml).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it will take some time to cut through it. On a first impressions, it seems like the XML transformation is defined in multiple, complex looking steps in Soup. I wonder if it would be easier to re-structure the XML using a single XSLT step however - I'm fluent in XSLT and the structure changes I desire a trivial (no grouping or such).

Comment: now you got me, the only time I used an XSLT step was with the help of people from the Pentaho forum, to make my XML more easily readable by humans. Reading the question again, I think I overkilled making almost a tutorial about XML on Kettle - from what I see now, you need to, kinda, mix and match reading an already existing XML with some alterations, adding attributes to elements, correct?